# Start HTML5 video with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I would like to play a video inside, which is next to #video-overlay, the code is:

```
jQuery(".landing-container #video-overlay").hover(function(){
        this.prev().play();
    },function(){
        this.prev().pause();
    });
```

If I change the function and I use `"video"` instead of `#video-overlay` and I remove the `prev()` everything fine..

What is the perfect solution? I would like to start the video on `#video-overlay` hover.

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM [**`Element`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object doesn't support `.prev()` method, for using jQuery [**`.prev()`**](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) method, the element should be wrapped with jQuery:

```
$("#video-overlay").hover(function() {
   $(this).prev().get(0).play();
              // ^-- Get the first selected DOM Element object from jQuery Collection
              //     for calling `.play` method, assuming the returned element is
              //     a Video or Audio Element object
  }, function() {
     $(this).prev().get(0).pause();
});
```

Using DOM Element object's [**`previousElementSibling`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.previousElementSibling) property (*doesn't work on IE8 and below*):

```
$("#video-overlay").hover(function() {
     this.previousElementSibling.play();
  }, function(){
     this.previousElementSibling.pause();
});
```